# How to fetch custom column which does not exist in database table?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I implement followig SQL QUERY  in django rest framework

```
`SELECT `id` , `name_hi` as hi , `name_en` as en ,  false as `checked` FROM `tab_name`
```

where checked does not exist in the database table i.e. it is not a column .

```html
id | hi | en | checked
1  | xx | xx | 0
2  | hi2| en2| 0
3  | hi3| en3| 0
```

I am using Django Rest framework.
How can I rename these fields also include checked

So far I have tried in serializer

```html
class TabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  hi = serializers.CharField(source='name_en')
  en = serializers.CharField(source='name_en')

    class Meta:
        model = Tab
        fields =('id','name_en','name_hi')
```

> It just return id name_en and name_hi irrespective of hi ,en and checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it in serializer for column alias

1. For column table alias

```html
class TabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  hi = serializers.CharField(source='name_hi')
  en = serializers.CharField(source='name_en')

    class Meta:
        model = TabFaultOption
        fields =('id','hi','en')
```

2. Now for column which does not exist in the database you need to change in the related model

model.py

```html
class Tab(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name_hi = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    checked=False
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tab'
```

Now in serializer include the checked column

```html
 class TabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      hi = serializers.CharField(source='name_en')
      en = serializers.CharField(source='name_en')
       checked= false
        class Meta:
            model = Tab
            fields =('id','hi','en','checked')
```